# Using Babel with PhantomJS, evaluate function being executed in browser context doesn't have access to helper functions

Tags: phantomjs, babeljs

I'm trying to use PhantomJS with a script that's compiled by Babel from ES6 to ES5.

For some of the features, Babel puts in some helper functions at the end of the file (like `_asyncToGenerator` and `_typeof`) to evaluate the code.

But in Phantom, there's a function `evaluate(function(){…})` which is executed in the browser context, so it doesn't have access to those helper functions babel puts in.

Ex, if I have a code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function(status) {
  var title = page.evaluate(function() {
    typeof(document.title);
  });
});
```

It compiles to

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function(status) {
  var title = page.evaluate(function Executed_in_Browser_Context() {
    _typeof(document.title);
  });
});
function _typeof(obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && obj.constructor === Symbol ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }
```

Notice the `typeof` has been changed to `_typeof` (for some feature involving ES6 Symbols)

Here, the `function Executed_in_Browser_Context` is executed in browser context, and so it doesn't have access to the `function _typeof` defined in the file at the bottom. And so it results in error

```
Can't find variable: _typeof
```

How to solve this?

I tried copying the `_typeof` inside `Executed_in_Browser_Context` (pre-compilation) but then upon compiling, Babel sees that and thinks that it may be some other function that I have in my code, and just renames its own to `_typeof2` resulting in same error.